# imakeidx \see clash with \backmatter

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, imakeidx

I wonder if someone could explain what's happening in the following MWE, where the use of `\backmatter` will make disappear the index crossed-refs (`\see` and `\seealso` commands); try uncommenting `\backmatter` and you will see. I never had this problem with ye old indexing packages, but now that I am enjoying `imakeidx`, it would be good to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex

\begin{document}
bla bla \index{bla} bla

\newpage
 ...relativity\index{relativity} ... Einstein\index{Einstein, Albert}...bla bla \index{bla} bla bla more bla bla \index{bla} bla

And this is the end of the story.

%\backmatter
\index{scientist|see{Einstein, Albert}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you. But I'm just wondering what would be a way to preserve the current document structure. I guess it must be a little clash between the definition of `\backmatter` and something in `imakeidx`, and I guess it must also be very simple to spot for those who know the innards of `imakeidx`.

Comment: Juan del Acebo: I try to figure out, but our top-rep user `egreg` is the author and maintainer of `imakeidx`, perhaps he knows more

Comment: Add a word between `\backmatter` and `\index{scientist...}` and it will work. This has to do with the delayed writing: in your example there's *no* page the index entry can refer to.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for trying. It does make the trick, but the problem with adding a word (I tried adding `\textit{ }`) is that a new unwanted page is generated before the index.

Comment: @JuandelAcebo What's the reason for adding `\index` after `\backmatter` without any accompanying text? I see none. Just put `\index` *before* `\backmatter`

Comment: @egreg I guess it's just a habit I got into of having all index cross-refs in one single place right before `printindex`, but it doesn't need to be so and I appreciate your answer below which I have marked as closing the case. Grazie mille

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The writing of an index entry in the `.idx` file happens when the page where the `\index` command eventually appears.

In order to be able to compile the index on the fly, that is using MakeIndex for transforming the `.idx` file into the `.ind` file containing LaTeX instructions, `imakeidx` closes the `.idx` file when LaTeX encounters `\printindex`.

In your example, `\backmatter` issues `\cleardoublepage`, so TeX is on a fresh page. The command `\index{scientist|see{Einstein, Albert}}` doesn't produce any box on this page. After this, `\printindex` closes the `.idx` file, so the `\index` command has had no chance of being written on this file, because no page has been shipped out since the command has been processed.

If you want to add “see” entries in a single place, the solution is to put them *before* `\backmatter`, or else to disable the automatic run of MakeIndex with the option `noautomatic` to `imakeidx` (which requires manually running MakeIndex and then rerunning LaTeX).

I'd probably put them after `\begin{document}` or in an external file to be `\input` after `\begin{document}`.

Just as an exercise, but don't take it too seriously, here's a way for adding the index cross references just before `\printindex`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{crossreferences}
 {\patchcmd{\protected@write}{\let\thepage\relax}{}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\protected@write}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
bla bla \index{bla} bla

\newpage
 ...relativity\index{relativity} ... Einstein\index{Einstein, Albert}...bla bla \index{bla} bla bla more bla bla \index{bla} bla

And this is the end of the story.

\backmatter
\begin{crossreferences}
\index{scientist|see{Einstein, Albert}}
\end{crossreferences}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Inside the `crossreferences` environment, `\write` is changed into `\immediate\write` and the setting that `\protected@write` does to `\thepage` is removed. Don't add “real” index entries in the environment (it wouldn't make much sense anyway).